# How to Import the Jar file in Java class file?

Tags: java

I want to include the Jar files while the class files is running.

```
import java.voce;
 public class SpeechInterface
 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
    voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize("hello world"); 

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below command to get your compiled class file:

**javac -cp .;<jar_file>.jar <src_file>.java**

For example,

**javac -cp .;Demo.jar Src_File.java**